# Flexslider carousel using template.php

Tags: javascript

**Views** with **flexslider** takes lot of times in rendering items/images.

Situation is that I have more than 5 flexslider carousels on the front page.
So I changed to go without view with flexslider.

I am trying to use flexslider carousel using template file.
Due to flexslider.css, I am not able to see `.slides>li` .

See following lines:

```
.flexslider .slides > li {
    display: none;
}
```

Even not able to see any slider movement there. Somehow I tried according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7539542/trying-to-get-flexslider-jquery-slider-to-work-with-drupal

Can anybody help me to create flexslider without view or manage display?
I want to create using tpl files.

Answer (score 0):

The common and very accepted way is to use a module and do everything from the UI:

I used Flexslider and it's a great module - If I remember correctly, you can use it's **field** display-option directly, without using Views. An "Instant" slider alternative could be the module "[Content glider](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_glider)", but I'm not sure if it's responsive (the word responsive doesn't come up in the modules' page) so Better try the Flexslider **field set** first.

For better performance in slider image-replacement (and in general) you could try turning on Caching and Aggregation, and use modules like AvgAgg, Boost, and some others, it's a whole subject.

Comment: Thanks for reply! but I donot want to apply caching here because content is changing here so often & one page containing more than 5 flexslider according content attached to term id. that means 10 contents in each row with flexslider & each row is filtered by term id.

Comment: Surly it's better to apply caching after all is done...